# adding an error / removing an error in jquery.validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to implement a generic way of adding remote validation to xVal / jquery.validate

There are only two unsolved questions left:

- How do I "manually" mark a form element as invalid and add an error message to it from my own javascript code?
- How do I remove remove the error message at a later time without removing any other error messages?

Is there any neat way to do this or do I have to hack a solution that takes into account how jquery.validate works internally?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found a much better way to solve this and wrote a blog article [on how to implement remote client-side validation](https://devermind.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-3-how-to-cover-all-your-client-side-form-validation-needs-without-writing-any-javascript-part1/) in a generic way in case someone else is also interested in remote client-side validation.

Comment: Your link looks like it's broken... can you post a solution here?